# How to get @servestamp firestore after add new Document

Tags: android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

I add some data to firestore which contain @serverstamp, but after I add data , I need to get @serverstamp for other progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using server side generated timestamps you'll need to query the created document to read the actual timestamp value. Nonetheless, if you need the timestamp maybe it would be more practical to generate the timestamp client side, so the document read isn't needed.